# Using a csv file with imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have this script that works with imacros, but when i convert the code to javascript its giving me an error: **"Data source file does not exist, line: 1 "**

The script is simple, it gets the info from line 1 on the csv file and submits it as a comment on a site.

I'm guessing the way the data source info is set is not cooperating with javascript so how should I do this,

```
var startingUrl;
startingUrl = "CODE:";
startingUrl += "URL GOTO=http://example.com";

var inputInfo;
inputInfo = "CODE:";
inputInfo += "SET !DATASOURCE E:\example.csv" + "\n";
inputInfo += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5" + "\n";
inputInfo += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
inputInfo += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:input ATTR=NAME:comment CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
inputInfo += "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";
inputInfo += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:input ATTR=VALUE:Submit" + "\n";

iimPlay(startingUrl);
iimPlay(inputInfo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double-slash:

```
inputInfo += "SET !DATASOURCE E:\\example.csv" + "\n";
```

Comment: omg i cant believe it was that easy, ive been trying to figure this out for a while. Thanks!